# Excel VBA: Open UTF-16 XML

Tags: xml, excel, vba, utf-16, byte-order-mark

I'm currently struggling to open up a utf-16 encoded XML file with VBA in Excel.

My current String variable titled EntireFile currently begins like this:

```
ÿþ<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

As you can see there are some characters in the beginning that seem off.

I get the String variable by doing:

```
Open PathToFile For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
              Line Input #1, textline
              EntireFile = EntireFile & textline
```

File is formatted with UCS-2 Little Endian according to Notepad++ but a quick search trough the internet revealed that this is the Microsoft equivalent to UTF-16?

I tried the bruteforce method of just removing the first two characters but that leaves me with an empty string.

All of the google results cover saving a XML file without the BOM but thats kind of the opposite of what I'm looking for.

Thanks already for your time

Answer (score 1):

You can use Win32 API Functions to convert encodings.

```
Private Declare Function WideCharToMultiByte Lib "kernel32.dll" ( _
                         ByVal CodePage As Long, _
                         ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
                         ByVal lpWideCharStr As Long, _
                         ByVal cchWideChar As Long, _
                         ByVal lpMultiByteStr As Long, _
                         ByVal cbMultiByte As Long, _
                         ByVal lpDefaultChar As Long, _
                         ByVal lpUsedDefaultChar As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function MultiByteToWideChar Lib "kernel32.dll" ( _
                         ByVal CodePage As Long, _
                         ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
                         ByVal lpMultiByteStr As Long, _
                         ByVal cbMultiByte As Long, _
                         ByVal lpWideCharStr As Long, _
                         ByVal cchWideChar As Long) As Long

Private Const CP_UTF16 As Long = 1200&

Private Function ConvertToUTF16(ByRef Source As String) As Byte()

    Dim Length As Long
    Dim Pointer As Long
    Dim Size As Long
    Dim Buffer() As Byte

    Length = Len(Source)
    Pointer = StrPtr(Source)
    Size = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF16, 0, Pointer, Length, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    ReDim Buffer(0 To Size - 1)

    WideCharToMultiByte CP_UTF16, 0, Pointer, Length, VarPtr(Buffer(0)), _
        Size, 0, 0

    ConvertToUTF16 = Buffer

End Function

Private Function ConvertFromUTF16(ByRef Source() As Byte) As String

    Dim Size As Long
    Dim Pointer As Long
    Dim Length As Long
    Dim Buffer As String

    Size = UBound(Source) - LBound(Source) + 1
    Pointer = VarPtr(Source(LBound(Source)))
    Length = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF16, 0, Pointer, Size, 0, 0)
    Buffer = Space$(Length)
    MultiByteToWideChar CP_UTF16, 0, Pointer, Size, StrPtr(Buffer), Length
    ConvertFromUTF16 = Buffer

End Function
```

`Private Const CP_UTF16 As Long = 1200&` means codepage 1200 which is UTF-16 little andian.

You can see a list of all codepages here https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried adding your code block as a module and calling the function CovertToUTF16 (which I made public) from inside my code with the EntireFile after it has been filled. WideCharToMultiByte gives me index out of bounds. I'm pretty sure thats an error on my end since this is an imported function but I have no clue where.

Comment: I went through the whole code again and found out that the imported function would propably perform as intended if Len(Source) didn't return 3000 (which clearly is wrong).